# Parsing CPLEX logfile to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, cplex

I'm trying to parse the Cplex Logfile for a MILP Problem to a Pandas Dataframe.
The Logfile Part for the Branch and Bound looks like this:

```
['  Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Ga',
 '',
 '     0+    0                            0.0000 -6819503.0000              ---',
 '     0     0  -149597.6789  3202        0.0000  -149597.6789       37     ---',
 '     0+    0                       -83655.0000  -149597.6789            78.83',
 '     0+    0                      -125854.0000  -149597.6789            18.87',
 '     0+    0                      -126474.0000  -149597.6789            18.28',
 '     0+    0                      -130810.0000  -138528.6611             5.90',
 '     0+    0                      -133740.0000  -135305.2732             1.17',
 '     0     2  -135305.2732  3622  -133740.0000  -135305.2732     6307    1.17',
 '    79    49  -135300.3578  3627  -133740.0000  -135304.7364     6743    1.17',
 '   207   172  -135294.5414  3606  -133740.0000  -135304.7364     8033    1.17',
 '   337   280  -135292.2563  3569  -133740.0000  -135304.7364     9140    1.17',
 '   457   433  -135294.0213  3591  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    10532    1.17',
 '   569   500  -135285.6607  3573  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    11117    1.17',
 '   627   559  -135282.5594  3559  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    11710    1.17',
 '   735   667  -135283.6653  3582  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    12619    1.17',
 '   815   688  -135281.1259  3574  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    12786    1.17',
 '   912   844  -135282.2331  3629  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    14043    1.17',
 '  1244  1085  -135267.1649  3544  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    16446    1.17',
 '  1458  1352  -135241.3260  3490  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    18874    1.17',
 '  1569  1487  -135230.0718  3454  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    20190    1.17',
 '  1607  1525  -135214.0255  3400  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    20599    1.17',
 '  1707  1590  -135196.7871  3372  -133740.0000  -135304.7364    21195    1.17',
 '  1818+ 1327                      -133837.0000  -135304.7364             1.10',
...
 ' 11004 10458  -134792.2319  2747  -134481.0000  -135304.7364   106870    0.61',
 ' 11005+ 9743                      -134482.0000  -135304.7364             0.61',
 ' 11005 10377  -135051.5669  3342  -134482.0000  -135304.7364   106128    0.61',
 ' 11006+ 9743                      -134485.0000  -135304.7364             0.61',
 ' 11007  9697  -135085.5502  3356  -134485.0000  -135304.7364   100103    0.61']
```

My Problem is if I try to read it with Pandas the missing values are shifting the values in the wrong cells.

```
    Node    Left    Objective   IInf    BestInteger BestBound   ItCnt   Gap
0   0+  0   0.0000          -6.819503e+06   --- NaN         NaN NaN
1   0   0   -149597.6789    3.202000e+03    0.0000  -149597.6789    37.0    ---
2   0+  0   -83655.0000 -1.495977e+05   78.83   NaN         NaN NaN
3   0+  0   -125854.0000    -1.495977e+05   18.87   NaN         NaN NaN
4   0+  0   -126474.0000    -1.495977e+05   18.28   NaN         NaN NaN
5   0+  0   -130810.0000    -1.385287e+05   5.90    NaN         NaN NaN
6   0+  0   -133740.0000    -1.353053e+05   1.17    NaN         NaN NaN
7   0   2   -135305.2732    3.622000e+03    -133740.0000    -135305.2732    6307.0  1.17
8   79  49  -135300.3578    3.627000e+03    -133740.0000    -135304.7364    6743.0  1.17
9   207 172 -135294.5414    3.606000e+03    -133740.0000    -135304.7364    8033.0  1.17
```

I used the following line to parse my list to pandas:

```py
test = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("\n".join(milp_log)), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read your strings as a fixed-width file using [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO('\n'.join(milp_log)))
```

Output:

```
     Node  Left    Objective    IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound     ItCnt     Ga
0       0+    0          NaN     NaN           0.0 -6.819503e+06       NaN    ---
1       0     0 -149597.6789  3202.0           0.0 -1.495977e+05      37.0    ---
2       0+    0          NaN     NaN      -83655.0 -1.495977e+05       NaN  78.83
3       0+    0          NaN     NaN     -125854.0 -1.495977e+05       NaN  18.87
4       0+    0          NaN     NaN     -126474.0 -1.495977e+05       NaN  18.28
5       0+    0          NaN     NaN     -130810.0 -1.385287e+05       NaN   5.90
6       0+    0          NaN     NaN     -133740.0 -1.353053e+05       NaN   1.17
7       0     2 -135305.2732  3622.0     -133740.0 -1.353053e+05    6307.0   1.17
8      79    49 -135300.3578  3627.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05    6743.0   1.17
9     207   172 -135294.5414  3606.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05    8033.0   1.17
10    337   280 -135292.2563  3569.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05    9140.0   1.17
11    457   433 -135294.0213  3591.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   10532.0   1.17
12    569   500 -135285.6607  3573.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   11117.0   1.17
13    627   559 -135282.5594  3559.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   11710.0   1.17
14    735   667 -135283.6653  3582.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   12619.0   1.17
15    815   688 -135281.1259  3574.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   12786.0   1.17
16    912   844 -135282.2331  3629.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   14043.0   1.17
17   1244  1085 -135267.1649  3544.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   16446.0   1.17
18   1458  1352 -135241.3260  3490.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   18874.0   1.17
19   1569  1487 -135230.0718  3454.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   20190.0   1.17
20   1607  1525 -135214.0255  3400.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   20599.0   1.17
21   1707  1590 -135196.7871  3372.0     -133740.0 -1.353047e+05   21195.0   1.17
22   1818+ 1327          NaN     NaN     -133837.0 -1.353047e+05       NaN   1.10
23  11004 10458 -134792.2319  2747.0     -134481.0 -1.353047e+05  106870.0   0.61
24  11005+ 9743          NaN     NaN     -134482.0 -1.353047e+05       NaN   0.61
25  11005 10377 -135051.5669  3342.0     -134482.0 -1.353047e+05  106128.0   0.61
26  11006+ 9743          NaN     NaN     -134485.0 -1.353047e+05       NaN   0.61
27  11007  9697 -135085.5502  3356.0     -134485.0 -1.353047e+05  100103.0   0.61
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to address this is to add a callback into CPLEX which can then output the information that you need in a format that works for you more easily. We have done this to report progress in real time for long solves as well as to create charts or graphs of the convergence. Can also be used to add custom termination of the search such as stopping if there is no improved solution for more than a minute.

Comment: Im using CPLEX via JuMP. How can i access these Informations ?

Comment: If using JuMP the options for callbacks seem a bit more limited (see https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/callbacks/) unless you are prepared to go down to the C API calls to get access to the full set of features in CPLEX